# Bluetooth forgets PIN

Tags: android, bluetooth

So I am working on an App that connects to an embedded Bluetooth Device. This device is rolled out in different versions and on my test device, everyting works just fine. Communicating via secure rfcomm socket. However, another set of devices give me the creeps. They kind of lose the bounding state. While they are marked as paired, everytime I establish a connection, I am asked to re-enter the PIN code. And this is really not desired. Also, this behavior doesnt occure on all, but most devices. Actually, the only device that does not forget the PIN is the Galaxy Nexus S. Samsung Galaxy Nexus, ACE, GIO and X10 mini Pro tend to "forget" the device was previously paired. Using API lvl 10, I have already tried insecure RFCOMM connec, but without success.
I am lost here. Has anyone an idea?

Best regards!

Comment: have you checked the android sample Bluetooth chat application ? it provides fully function chat via bluetooth and i'v tried it and it works without an issue. give it a try.

Comment: I wish I could vote down... Hehe, just kidding. But yes, ofcourse I did. I have spent hours with the reference implementation. I have spent more hours with the AIDL hack to reflect the hidden bluetooth classes to establish a programatic connection. I have spent many hours checking dozends of google links and implementations. I have spent hours reading through the Bluetooth sepcifications on Wiki and almost everything I could find here on SO...

Comment: @JohnSmith Unfortunatelly there's not way to downvote comments... Back to your question which method are you calling when you're trying to retrive the socket?

Comment: I follow the reference implementation of the Bluetooth Chat Service example we all know. The connect thread is initialized with the remote device. Then, the BluetoothSocket is being retrieved from createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")) SPP UUID. 
When the thread is executed, the block function call socket.connect() is being invoked and if no exception has been thrown, a function connect is being called. the connect-thread get's closed and the opened socket is passed to the connected-thread constructor. run() then reads the input stream.

Comment: I want to repeat that this way works perfectly for a certain set of bluetooth devices while not for others. Currently there are three sets of remote devices. One works with all mobile phones, another set works just with Galaxy Nexus S and a third set of devices not sufficient. The connection and also communication works with all devices! It's just that two out of three device types require re-entering the pin code every time a new connec is established.

Comment: I am still trying to pair devices programatically but without success. Also, rooting the target mobile devices is not an option for our client.

Comment: @JohnSmith OK, I made a few test here and might get it. How are you getting the device that creates the socket? It's through an intent or MAC adress?

Comment: Through its MAC. The discovering process is ran before and I want to express that I surely call cancelDiscovery() (was it called cancelDiscovery()? Gotta check the code...) before I create the Socket

Comment: Oh, I'm running out of cards, the test that I made here, if you know the MAC and call createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(); he didn't ask the device, but as you said, you already tried it... So I really don't know...

Comment: Thanks for the input though. I am also stuck at this. The devices that used to connect to these kind of devices solve this on a fairly low-level by use of specialized chip that simply gives the client device the desired pin any time it asks for it. Talkin to the tech department, there is also no chance to upgrade any firmware whatsoever. What bugs me is the fact that it performs well on the Nexus S but no other device we have tested so far. I am not much of a low-level guy but I assume that the Nexus S adapter establishes the connection just slightly different than the others do...

Comment: ... and this causes the remote device to request authentification every single time. If there was a chance to send the pin programatically to the remote device, I would just do that everytime a pairing request is received.

Comment: Well, can't help from here. Your problem seems much more political than programatically. Hope you can find a way to solve it, and if you do please post the answer here. Cheers!

Comment: I sure will do that. Cheers

Comment: @Rigotti Ok, it's a manifacturer issue. All new devices work properly. Thanks for the help. Cheers!

Comment: Ohh, hell... Well, at least it's not your problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the getBTMajorDeviceClass of your device?
If it is BluetoothClass.Device.Major.UNCATEGORIZED, try to generate your own UUID:

```
private UUID generateUuid() {
String android_id = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext()
    .getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
Log.i("System out", "android_id : " + android_id);

final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

final String tmDevice, tmSerial, androidId;
tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
Log.i("System out", "tmDevice : " + tmDevice);
tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();
Log.i("System out", "tmSerial : " + tmSerial);
androidId = ""
    + android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(
        getContentResolver(),
        android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(androidId.hashCode(),
    ((long) tmDevice.hashCode() << 32) | tmSerial.hashCode());

return deviceUuid;
}
```

and use it on socket creation `createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(generateUuid());`

*Requires READ_PHONE_STATE